# Is it possible to add Extra custom keyword to c# program so that makes two int variables different types?

Tags: c#

I need to create two extra keywords `input` and `output` so I can have these decelerations in my c# code:

```
input int a;
input int b;
output int c;
swap (input int lhs, output int rhs) { ... }
swap(a,c) // should be compiled;
swap(c,a) // should return compile error
swap(a,b) // should return compile error
```

I also need compiler to accept `a = b` but reject `b = c` or `c = a`. Is it possible? Then if it is not possible what is the solution? I already use `Output<T>` and `Input<T>` as generic wrappers for all types but I hate using value getter and setter whenever I want to access the values inside these generic wrappers!

Comment: You could propose a change to the C# language (it's on github), even better create a PR for the change. But you'll need to have a really really really good case for that kind of change.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: "I hate using value getter and setter whenever I want to access the values inside these generic wrappers" - that sounds like you want to have implicit conversions from the wrapped types to the values, basically...

Comment: @JonSkeet Ahhh good point so you could probably use implicit operators.

Comment: @JonSkeet So you think the real solution is to use generics?

Comment: It's hard to say what the best solution is when you haven't really been clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is akin to asking for a way to create new types that are just basic primitives but with extra type information, to avoid combining and using them all willy nilly. For instance, you might say that the temperature of something is a double and the length of something is a double, but you want compiler help to ensure you're not using a temperature value where a length is needed, or vice versa. The only thing C# provides for you is that you can construct a struct that holds an int or double, but then you will need to implement a lot of the operators. Not hard, but there is no single-line way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public sealed class Input<T>
{
    public T value { get; set; }

    public Input(T v)
    {
        value = v;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Input<T> d)
    {
        return d.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Input<T>(T d)
    {
        return new Input<T>(d);
    }
}

public sealed class Output<T>
{
    public T value { get; set; }

    public Output(T v)
    {
        value = v;
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Output<T> d)
    {
        return d.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Output<T>(T d)
    {
        return new Output<T>(d);
    }
}
```

Then the swap method looks like:

```
    static void swap<T>(Input<T> input, Output<T> output)
    {
        output.value = input.value;
    }
```

And the usage:

```
            Input<int> myInput = 1;
            Input<int> myInput2 = 1;
            Output<int> myOutput = 0;

            swap(myInput, myOutput); //Compiles
            swap(myInput, myInput2); //Error
            swap(myOutput, myInput); //Error
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the reason of why you need this but this trick just came to my mind... that you could use primitive types as wrappers

```
            double a = 0.0;
            int b = 1;
            float c = 3;

            //this will compile 
            a = b;

            //these will give compile error
            b = c;
            c = a;
```